# How to stop the XML being returned by a list view web part from truncating a value

Tags: 2010, web-part, list-view

I have an Announcements list. In my view I am returning the body. When displaying the body field in a list web part, the body field is being truncated and '...' is added to the end. When viewing the view not in a web part the '...' is not added. How can I get the list part view not to truncate the data?

Comment: Can you clarify what is "list web part"? I'm adding Announcements to a webpartpage, when modifying view - adding the body field - and then I can see all the contents of the field, even if it is huge. It is not being truncated.

Comment: I am using Lists and Libraries > My list name (It has a megaphone next to it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're using `<Summary view>`:

[image]

To get full descriptions, just select "All items" view from webpart properties:

[image]

, and add the Body column using "Modify view" ribbon button:

[image]

However, if it doesn't satisfy your needs (because "All items" view looks like a table), you will need some additional XSLT coding.

**Creating analogue for summary view with uncut Body field**

First of all, ensure that Announcements list is currently displayed in "table" mode, and `Body` and `Created by` fields are added into the view.

Open the page in SharePoint designer, switch to Code tab, and add `<Xsl>` tag to the XsltListViewWebPart markup.

Finally, paste the following code to the `<Xsl>` tag:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"> 

    <xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/main.xsl"/>
    <xsl:include href="/_layouts/xsl/internal.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$RenderCTXOnly='True'">
            <xsl:call-template name="CTXGeneration"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="($ManualRefresh = 'True')">
            <xsl:call-template name="AjaxWrapper" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="RootTemplate" select="$XmlDefinition">
                <xsl:with-param name="ShowSelectAllCheckbox" select="false"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template mode="header" match="FieldRef" />

    <xsl:template mode="Item" match="Row">

        <xsl:param name="Fields" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="Collapse" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="Position" select="1" />
        <xsl:param name="Last" select="1" />
        <xsl:variable name="thisNode" select="."/>
        <tr>
          <td width="80%" class="ms-vb" style="padding-bottom: 3px">
            <span class="ms-announcementtitle">
              <a onfocus="OnLink(this)"
                 href="{$FORM_DISPLAY}&amp;ID={$thisNode/@ID}"
                 onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;" target="_self">
                <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Title"/>
              </a>
              <xsl:if test="$thisNode/@Created_x0020_Date.ifnew='1'">
                <xsl:call-template name="NewGif">
                  <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:call-template name="FieldRef_Attachments_body">
                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
              </xsl:call-template>
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
            </span>
            <br />
            <xsl:value-of select="'by'"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$thisNode/@Author.span"/>
          </td>
          <td width="20%" align="right" nowrap="nowrap" class="ms-vb">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Modified"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="ms-vb">
            <div>
              <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Body" disable-output-escaping ="yes"/>
            </div>
            <!-- output the remaining fields -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$Fields[not(@Name='LinkTitle' or @Name='Modified' or @Name='Author' or @Name='Body' or @Name='Attachments')]">
              <br />
              <xsl:value-of select="@DisplayName"/>:
              <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="PrintFieldWithDisplayFormLink">
                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="$thisNode"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <font size="1">
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" ddwrt:nbsp-preserve="yes">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:text>
            </font>
          </td>
        </tr>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You will get exactly the same view as `Summary view`, but with uncut description.

Looks a bit complicated, huh? :) Actually mostly it's a copy-paste from OOTB SharePoint `vwstyles.xsl` file, with some pointed corrections. Creating this XSLT only took about 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen this is a built in setting in SharePoint that I don't think can be easily changed. Some body fields could have thousands of words because of the field type. I could only suggest creating a custom page if you wanted to display all the contents of the body field.